# Calling service with localhost or machine IP for internal calls?

Tags: networking, deployment, localhost, ip

What is better calling services from localhost IP which is 127.0.0.1 or calling services from machine IP because services resided under same system, and what if I call services with Machine IP will it hop over the network or it will loopback since it's same machine IP?